# Where can I put the $scope into the controller in that way?

Tags: angularjs, filter, controller

If I would put the $scope in tht controller, where I should put it?

```
angular.module('FilterInControllerModule', []).
      controller('FilterController', ['filterFilter', function(filterFilter) {
        this.array = [
          {name: 'Tobias'},
          {name: 'Jeff'},
          {name: 'Brian'},
          {name: 'Igor'},
          {name: 'James'},
          {name: 'Brad'}
        ];
        this.filteredArray = filterFilter(this.array, 'a');
      }]);
```

Comment: `controller('FilterController', ['filterFilter', '$scope', function(filterFilter , $scope) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the array as the second parameter of controller method. But you don't need to specify the whole array. You can just pass it as the parameter of the controller function.

```
controller('FilterController', function(filterFilter, $scope) {
    this.array = [
      {name: 'Tobias'},
      {name: 'Jeff'},
      {name: 'Brian'},
      {name: 'Igor'},
      {name: 'James'},
      {name: 'Brad'}
    ];
    this.filteredArray = filterFilter(this.array, 'a');
  });
```

Comment: I think using $scope.array =[your data]; and $scope.filteredArray = filterFilter(this.array, 'a'); is cleaner way.

Comment: @DilipKumar it doesn't work as you wrote